# PHP script not indexing my PostgreSQL array properly

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm facing a problem with reading an associative array from an SQL query on my PostgreSQL database.

So here's my database:

```
ID | NAME | ....
1  | CARS | 
2  | BIKES| 
3  | TRAINS |
```

Now I have a PHP script that I want to grab some data from that query and encode it into `JSON` for a mobile device.

Here is the script:

```
    $res = pg_query("SELECT * FROM projects");

/* FETCHES THE RESULT OF THE SQL QUERY WHICH GETS THE NAME OF EACH PROJECT */
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $output[]=$row['name'];
    print (json_encode($output));
}  /* CONVERTED ON MOBILE PLATFORM */

pg_close();
```

Now the result I'm getting is shown copy and pasted from the output of the file (below):

```
["Cars"]["Cars","Bikes"]["Cars","Bikes","Trains"]
```

I can clearly see that my algorithm is indexing the records is a sort of 1, 1,2, 1,2,3 kind of way. Has anyone got any advice on how to solve this and to get this output:

```
["Cars"]["Bikes"]["Trains"]
```

Comment: What happens if you change `$output[]` to `$output`?

Comment: @mavroprovato it produces "Cars", "Bikes", "Trains" without the `[]`! I believe that is what I want but are they separate values or an individual value? I need them to be separate as I'm populating a spinner on an android device!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just print the array at the end, after it was fully populated:

```
$res = pg_query("SELECT * FROM projects");

/* FETCHES THE RESULT OF THE SQL QUERY WHICH GETS THE NAME OF EACH PROJECT */
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $output[]=$row['name'];
}  /* CONVERTED ON MOBILE PLATFORM */

print (json_encode($output));

pg_close();
```

Alternatively, you could reinitialize the $output array if you need to output the individually. Depends on what you want to achieve:

```
$res = pg_query("SELECT * FROM projects");

/* FETCHES THE RESULT OF THE SQL QUERY WHICH GETS THE NAME OF EACH PROJECT */
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $output = array();
    $output[]=$row['name'];
    print (json_encode($output));
}  /* CONVERTED ON MOBILE PLATFORM */

pg_close();
```

Comment: second solution suggested gave the result `["Cars", "Bikes", "Trains"]` which is three separate values in an array. Cheers :)

Comment: sure, good luck. i'll edit the answer to highlight the desired solution.